# Parallelize a loop in python 2.4

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-2.4

I have some code that looks like this:

```
for item in list:
    <bunch of slow python code, depending only on item>
```

I want to speed this up by parallelizing the loop. Normally the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module would be perfect for this (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9786102/789750)), but it was added in python 2.6 and I'm stuck using 2.4.

What's the best way to parallelize a python loop in python 2.4?

Comment: Are you really stuck in python 2.4? Even if you're using an old Linux system you can usually compile your own build of a later version of Python (heck, even Python 3.x), and then put it into a local directory so that it doesn't interfere with the system default.

Comment: Also, you can write the slow portion of the code in C and use threading. Threading doesn't suffer from the Global Interpreter Lock problem when you aren't using the interpreter in low-level C code.

Comment: @mlefavor: I've actually got python3.2 installed in my home directory, but the `<slow python code>` depends on a bunch of libraries (matplotlib, scipy, and some in-house stuff) I don't want to install myself. It's the same reason I don't want to rewrite it in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for "fork," which will make it easy to use the specific item.

- http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/os-process.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29#Example_in_Python

Your for loop will need to look a little different, though -- you want to break out as soon as fork returns zero.

```
import os

L = ["a", "b", "c"]

for item in L:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0: break
    else: print "Forked:", pid

if pid != 0: print "Main Execution, Ends"
else: print "Execution:", item
```

Comment: This could cause a problem is the list is very long (hundreds of items in the list). Since this is normally the case, is there an easy way to ensure that only `n` forked processes are running at one time?

Comment: Figured it out; I can just use numpy.array_split().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using python 2.4, but have you tried using subprocess.Popen and just spawning new processes?

```
from subprocess import Popen

for x in range(n):
    processes.append(Popen('python doWork.py',shell = True))

for process in processes: 
    process.wait()
```