# How to manage python threads and assign them tasks by round robin?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, twitter, round-robin

I'm iterating over several JSON objects at several files. I will make Twitter API calls with some parameters from such JSON objects.

However, Twitter API got a limit and I can't exceed more than [180 calls per a 15 minutes period.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid)

API calls are executed using a library, let's call `api` the object which makes the calls.

Having one, I would use a `sleep` every time I get to the limit and after the wait I'd continue. However, as I can use more than one `api` object for different Twitter apps, I'd like to assign them the call statements and make them wait if necessary but not making the other `api` stop if not necessary or the whole execution.

Let's say I have:

```
api1, api2, api3, api4, api5 ... api10
```

This is the code where I iterate and get to the point of API call:

```
for f in os.listdir('tweets'):
            #print f
            with open('tweets/'+f,'r', buffering=1) as jsonQuery:
                twitterJSON = json.load(jsonQuery)
                for category in twitterJSON:
                    for trend in twitterJSON[category]:
                        j = 0
                        for t in twitterJSON[category][trend]:
                            self.dist=[]
                            values = []

                            # I'd make the call here for 
                            # any of the api variables which gets its turn.
```

How can I thread the task at loop and round robin to any of the `api`'s?

Comment: Do you need 'round robin'? This confuses me. One can parallelize your code. If you want a special sheduler this becomes more difficult.

Comment: I think is more simple than what I maybe suggested.

I want n api instances doing queries at same time and waiting when they have to (180 queries per second). Why did I mentioned round robin? Because at loop they receive an argument for querying, I thought by round robin any api instance would be picked for the task

Comment: How does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop) relate to your question?