# Parallelize this nested for loop in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm struggling again to improve the execution time of this piece of code. Since the calculations are really time-consuming I think that the best solution would be to parallelize the code.

I was first working with maps as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217088/parallelize-a-nested-for-loop-in-python-for-finding-the-max-value) question, but then I tried a more simple approach thinking that I could find a better solution. However I couldn't come up with anything yet, so since it's a different problem I decided to post it as a new question.

I am working on a Windows platform, using Python 3.4.

Here's the code:

```
similarity_matrix = [[0 for x in range(word_count)] for x in range(word_count)]
for i in range(0, word_count):
    for j in range(0, word_count):
        if i > j:
            similarity = calculate_similarity(t_matrix[i], t_matrix[j])
            similarity_matrix[i][j] = similarity
            similarity_matrix[j][i] = similarity
```

This is the `calculate_similarity` function:

```
def calculate_similarity(array_word1, array_word2):
      denominator = sum([array_word1[i] + array_word2[i] for i in range(word_count)])
      if denominator == 0:
          return 0
      numerator = sum([2 * min(array_word1[i], array_word2[i]) for i in range(word_count)])
      return numerator / denominator
```

And the explanation for the code:

- `word_count` is the total number of unique words stored in a list
- `t_matrix` is a matrix containing a value for each pair of words
- the output should be `similarity_matrix` whose dimension is `word_count x word_count` also containing a similarity value for each pair of words
- it's ok to keep both matrices in memory
- after these computations I can easily find the most similar word for each words (or the top three similar words, as the task may require)
- `calculate_similarity` takes two float lists, each for a separate word (each is a row in the t_matrix)

I work with a list of 13k words, and if I calculated correctly the execution time on my system would be a few days. So, anything that will do the job in one day would be wonderful!

Maybe only parellelizing the calculation of `numerator` and `denominator` in `calculate_similarity` would make a significant improvement.

Comment: as a matter of style, you could iterate the 'triangle' instead of the 'square' by changing the range in the second loop to be bounded by the `i` of the first loop.  you won't get much performance boost this way, but you will reduce one level of nesting .. :)

Comment: can you use different language. perhaps c++ and openmp?

Comment: @wim you mean `for j in range(i, word_count):` ? I already tried that but it changed almost nothing. @Coder Hacker If I really have no other option left, I would translate the code I we written so far. You think it would be easy to do it in C++?

Comment: What does `calculate_similarity()` look like?

Comment: It will definitely run faster in c++. Can you speed up calculate similarity function at all?

Comment: @jmunsch thanks for that, I'll use it, but it won't make any significant change in the speed because it is executed only once and even if it takes 10 mis that's nothing compared that in the nested loop there are about 85 million iterations  and each takes about 0.012 seconds :(

Comment: @jmunsch: Your code is faster because it doesn't actually allocate as many lists. If you add a value to one of the inner lists, you'll see it in all of the copies too, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: Take a look at @Blckknght's solution, it is a big improvement over mine. Also, you should remove the square brackets from the sums in `calculate_similarity`. For example `denominator = sum(array_word1[i] + array_word2[i] for i in range(word_count))`. Using a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) here, instead of a list comprehension, saves you from constructing a list and storing a lot of values just to sum them up an throw the list away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, Future, wait
from itertools import combinations
from functools import partial

similarity_matrix = [[0]*word_count for _ in range(word_count)]

def callback(i, j, future):
    similarity_matrix[i][j] = future.result()
    similarity_matrix[j][i] = future.result()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executer:
    fs = []
    for i, j in combinations(range(wordcount), 2):
        future = excuter.submit(
                    calculate_similarity, 
                    t_matrix[i], 
                    t_matrix[j])

        future.add_done_callback(partial(callback, i, j))
        fs.append(future)

    wait(fs)
```

Comment: The code works fine, but again I tested it with 350 words, but the execution time increased from 18 to 40 seconds. I also tried using ThreadPoolExecutor, but as I can see in the Task Manager it doesn't seem like it runs in parallel and the execution time is about 25 seconds.

Comment: I'd guess that the slowdown is due to overhead serializing the `t_matrix[i]` and `t_matrix[j]` items over and over. I know that with `multiprocessing.Pool` you can write a function to do one-time setup for the worker processes, but I'm not sure if you can do the same for a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Blckknght `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` doesn't support the `initializer` keyword argument right now. There is [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue21423) filed against this, with a working patch to add support for it, but it's still waiting to be reviewed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative implementation of the same general algorithm as in [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29223859/1405065), just using `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. It may be more efficient than his code, since the values of the input (`t_matrix`) are only serialized once and passed to the `initializer` function in each worker process.

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools

def worker_init(matrix):
    global worker_matrix
    worker_matrix = matrix

def worker(i, j):
    similarity = calculate_similarity(worker_matrix[i], worker_matrix[j])
    return i, j, similarity

def main(matrix):
    size = len(matrix)
    result = [[0]*size for _ in range(size)]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=worker_init, initargs=(matrix,)) as pool:
        for i, j, val in pool.starmap(worker, itertools.combinations(range(size), 2)):
            result[i][j] = result[j][i] = val
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get t_matrix from somewhere
    main(t_matrix)
```

Comment: `result = [[0]*size for _ in size]` should be `result = [[0]*size for _ in range(size)]`

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, you're right. I factored out the `len(matrix)` computation late in the coding process and ended up cutting too much in that spot.

Comment: This solution causes a memory error when computing the result. I'm not sure what can be the difference in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are using to many list comprehensions for such an amount of data. I would strongly recommend the `numpy` module.
If that is an option you can do:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

t = np.array(t_matrix)

s = np.sum(t,axis=1)

denom = s[:,None] + s[None,:]
num = np.zeros((word_count,word_count))

for i,j in itertools.product(range(word_count),repeat=2):
    num[i,j] = np.where(t[i] <= t[j], t[i], t[j]).sum()

similarity_matrix = np.where(denom != 0.0, 2.*num/denom, 0 )
```

Comment: There are still ways to improve that ... but first I would be interested whether it gives the same result as your code and how fast it is