# Python multiprocessing pool hangs on map call

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing

I have a function that parses a file and inserts the data into MySQL using SQLAlchemy. I've been running the function sequentially on the result of `os.listdir()` and everything works perfectly.

Because most of the time is spent reading the file and writing to the DB, I wanted to use multiprocessing to speed things up. Here is my pseduocode as the actual code is too long:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,features="lxml", from_encoding='utf-8')

    # parse file here

    db_record = MyDBRecord(parsed_data)

    session.add(db_record)
    session.commit()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

pool.map(parse_file, ['my_dir/' + filename for filename in os.listdir("my_dir")])
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the script hangs and never finishes. I usually get 48 of 63 records into the database. Sometimes it's more, sometimes it's less.

I've tried using `pool.close()` and in combination with `pool.join()` and neither seems to help.

How do I get this script to complete? What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python 2.7.8 on a Linux box.

Comment: Where does the `session` variable come from?

Comment: Doesn't the main code need to go in a function, otherwise it gets re-imported and run again?

Comment: @Kevin it comes from an import: `from db_classes import session` which looks like this:

`engine = create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost/my_db')`
`Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`
`Base.metadata.bind = engine`
`DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)`
`session = DBSession()`

Comment: Is it safe to share one session across multiple processes?  That seems weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a combination of 2 things:

1. my pool code being called multiple times (thanks @Peter Wood)
2. my DB code opening too many sessions (and/or) sharing sessions

I made the following changes and everything works now:
*Original File*

```
def parse_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,features="lxml", from_encoding='utf-8')

    # parse file here

    db_record = MyDBRecord(parsed_data)

    session = get_session() # see below
    session.add(db_record)
    session.commit()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

pool.map(parse_file, ['my_dir/' + filename for filename in os.listdir("my_dir")])
```

*DB File*

```
def get_session():
    engine = create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost/my_db')

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    db_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    return db_session()
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to put all code which uses multiprocessing, inside its own function. This stops it recursively launching new pools when multiprocessing re-imports your module in separate processes:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    ...

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(parse_file, ['my_dir/' + filename for filename in os.listdir("my_dir")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See the documentation about [making sure your module is importable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), also the [advice for running on Windows(tm)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)

Comment: is it equivalent to use "with"?

Comment: No, it’s not the same

Comment: small comment: there should be an extra ' after __main__ to close the string