# Python multiprocessing - values not appending to the list and the processes remain stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

My function:

```
value1 = []
value2 = []
def func_test(x):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    value1.append(x**3)
    value2.append(x+1)
```

The goal is to use the processor pools to parallely append values to the lists.

Here's what I did:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(func_test, [1,2,3,4,5])
```

The processes stays stuck. I am assuming it is probably because of **deadlock**. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Your code should work as calling `append()` on a list is thread safe. Are you sure it's stuck? Your sleep calls will mean it should take a couple seconds.

Comment: using windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995897/python-multiprocessing-pool-hangs-on-map-call

Comment: @MicahCarrick stuck over 5 minutes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ubuntu. but thaniks.

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: Also, are you running a script or doing this in the interactive interpreter? Multiprocessing won't play nice with the interactive interpreter.