# Multiprocessing : use tqdm to display a progress bar

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress-bar, tqdm

To make my code more "pythonic" and faster, I use `multiprocessing` and a map function to send it a) the function and b) the range of iterations.

The implanted solution (i.e., calling `tqdm` directly on the range `tqdm.tqdm(range(0, 30))`) does not work with multiprocessing (as formulated in the code below).

The progress bar is displayed from 0 to 100% (when python reads the code?) but it does not indicate the actual progress of the map function.

**How can one display a progress bar that indicates at which step the 'map' function is ?**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm
import time

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   time.sleep(1)
   return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   p = Pool(2)
   r = p.map(_foo, tqdm.tqdm(range(0, 30)))
   p.close()
   p.join()
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome...

Comment: Can you post the code snippet of the progress bar?

Comment: For people in search for a solution with `.starmap()`: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57364423/9059420) is a patch for `Pool` adding `.istarmap()`, which will also work with `tqdm`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Solution found. Be careful! Due to multiprocessing, the estimation time (iteration per loop, total time, etc.) could be unstable, but the progress bar works perfectly.

Note: Context manager for `Pool` is only available in Python 3.3+.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from tqdm import *

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   time.sleep(1)
   return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        max_ = 30
        with tqdm(total=max_) as pbar:
            for _ in p.imap_unordered(_foo, range(0, max_)):
                pbar.update()
```

Comment: `pbar.close()` not required, it will be closed automatically on termination of `with`

Comment: Is the second/inner `tqdm` call necessary here?

Comment: what about the output of the _foo(my_number) that is returned as "r" in question?

Comment: Is there a similar solution for `starmap()` ?

Comment: @shadowtalker - it seems to work without ;). Anyway - `imap_unordered` is key here, it gives best performance and best progress bar estimations.

Comment: Is ```enumerate``` really necessary? Why not ```for _ in p.imap_unordered(...):```

Comment: How do I retrieve the results with this solution?

Comment: instead of return square  in the function, add the result to a list

Answer (score 253):

Use `imap` instead of `map`, which returns an iterator of the processed values.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm
import time

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   time.sleep(1)
   return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Pool(2) as p:
      r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(_foo, range(30)), total=30))
```

Comment: I tried this solution. It worked, but for some reason, the call to `list()` is necessary, as well as passing the size of the list in the `total=` argument for `tqdm()`. Why is that?

Comment: An enclosing list() statement waits for the iterator to end. total= is also required since tqdm does not know how long the iteration will be,

Comment: Is there a similar solution for `starmap()` ?

Comment: `for i in tqdm.tqdm(...):     pass ` may be a more straight-forward, that `list(tqdm.tqdm)`

Comment: This works but has anyone else had it continuously print the progress bar on a newline for each iteration?

Comment: If you encounter locking issues while trying this solution, try removing the `tqdm.write()` statements from your code.

Comment: The behaviour is wired when specific `chunk_size` of `p.imap`. Can `tqdm` update every iteration instead of every chunk?

Comment: None of the answers worked for multithreading, though. Has anyone found a concise solution?

Comment: The method works; however, each bar is updated on the same line (overlapping progress bars for different processes). Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: @hkyi please can you elaborate more on why we need to call list(). thanks

Comment: The "patch" solution for starmap can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354700/starmap-combined-with-tqdm

Comment: I don't think this solution works properly. Stays in 0% for almost all the time, and suddenly goes to 100%.

Comment: @CarlosSouza That's because imap keep order, iterator won't skip unfinished items. You can use `imap_unordered`.

Answer (score 234):

Sorry for being late but if all you need is a concurrent map, I added this functionality in `tqdm>=4.42.0`:

```
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map  # or thread_map
import time

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   time.sleep(1)
   return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   r = process_map(_foo, range(0, 30), max_workers=2)
```

References: https://tqdm.github.io/docs/contrib.concurrent/ and https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/examples/parallel_bars.py

It supports `max_workers` and `chunksize` and you can also easily switch from `process_map` to `thread_map`.

Comment: Cool (+1), but throws `HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=30.0), HTML(value='')))` in Jupyter

Comment: @Ébe-Isaac see https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/937

Comment: I see an issue with discussion to hack tqdm_notebook, however, can't workout a solution to solve for tqdm.contrib.concurrent.

Comment: how to close the process with process_map? something like 'p.close()' and 'p.join()' ?

Comment: @Xudong `process_map` creates, runs , closes/joins and returns a list.

Comment: This is great! So glad I found it. One question remains, when I use this in a jupyter notebook, it doesn't work very well. I know there is a `tqdm.notebook`, is there someway to merge the two?

Comment: I report the same issues when using this in a jupyter notebook. Especially it crashes for `thread_map`

Comment: This makes unconditional copies of the iterated arguments, while the others seems to do copy-on-write.

Comment: Hmm.. finishes while the progress bar is stuck at zero.

Comment: If i pass in some kwargs (for instance, initargs, initializer - which are kwrgs for multiprocessing.Pool), does the wrapper pass them onto the Pool instance created? 

I can see it does pass through max_workers, and chunksize.

Comment: @jlconlin @Vladimir Vargas I don't have any issues if I do something like e.g. `thread_map(fn, *iterables, tqdm_class=tqdm.notebook.tqdm, max_workers=12)` in a Jupyter Notebook today.

Comment: Using this with requests gives me the wrong number of finished iterations. Prefer @SciPy solution

Comment: When I try this, my progress bar is stuck at zero and never updates.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the thread_map, which, looks weird with unrecognized texts, like "?" in a box. Something like ! box[?]t.t7...Done! box[?]box[?]box[?].., the bar shows 0%. I'm using it in Windows default command line.

Comment: Works perfectly here! Thnks

Comment: bizarre to include this functionality in tqdm. talk about scope creep

Comment: This produces "`OSError: handle is closed`" every time, when using it to read files in parallel on Mac in Python 3.11 run from Jupyter.  Seems to work ok in Linux, but not Mac.  Seems to be a bug in `ProcessPoolExecutor`.  Haven't found a fix other than to just not use `tqdm...process_map` anymore. :-(

Comment: For me it works 50% slower than just map with no tqdm. I might messed up something, but on my code with same run settings, I was getting 430 vs 250 seconds runtime on the same data.

Answer (score 36):

You can use `p_tqdm` instead.

https://github.com/swansonk14/p_tqdm

```
from p_tqdm import p_map
import time

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   time.sleep(1)
   return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   r = p_map(_foo, list(range(0, 30)))
```

Comment: This works extremely well, and it was very easy to `pip install`. This is replacing tqdm for most of my needs

Comment: Merci Victor ;)

Comment: `p_tqdm` is limited to `multiprocessing.Pool`, not available for threads

Comment: Can I specify the number of workers for p_map?

Comment: @VictorWang Yes use it in `num_cpus` like this => `p_map(_foo, list(range(0, 30)), num_cpus=5)`

Comment: How do I mention a description for the progress bar? In tqdm there is an argument called desc which can be provided with the description. I could not find something like that for p_tqdm.

Comment: @VandanRevanur You can pass kwargs to p_tqdm and they will be forwarded to tqdm, like so: https://github.com/swansonk14/p_tqdm/issues/5

Answer (score 10):

based on the answer of Xavi Martínez I wrote the function `imap_unordered_bar`. It can be used in the same way as `imap_unordered` with the only difference that a processing bar is shown.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from tqdm import *

def imap_unordered_bar(func, args, n_processes = 2):
    p = Pool(n_processes)
    res_list = []
    with tqdm(total = len(args)) as pbar:
        for i, res in tqdm(enumerate(p.imap_unordered(func, args))):
            pbar.update()
            res_list.append(res)
    pbar.close()
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return res_list

def _foo(my_number):
    square = my_number * my_number
    time.sleep(1)
    return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = imap_unordered_bar(_foo, range(5))
```

Comment: This will redraw the bar at each step on a new line. How to update the same line?

Comment: Solution in my case (Windows/Powershell): Colorama.

Comment: 'pbar.close() not required, it will be closed automatically on 
  termination of with'  like the comment Sagar made on @scipy's answer

Answer (score 7):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import tqdm


iterable = ... 
num_cpu = mp.cpu_count() - 2 # dont use all cpus.


def func():
    # your logic
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(num_cpu) as p:
        list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(func, iterable), total=len(iterable)))
```

Answer (score 7):

For progress bar with apply_async, we can use following code as suggested in:

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/484

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm import tqdm

def myfunc(a):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return a ** 2

pool = Pool(2)
pbar = tqdm(total=100)

def update(*a):
    pbar.update()

for i in range(pbar.total):
    pool.apply_async(myfunc, args=(i,), callback=update)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take for when you need to get results back from your parallel executing functions. This function does a few things (there is another post of mine that explains it further) but the key point is that there is a tasks pending queue and a tasks completed queue. As workers are done with each task in the pending queue they add the results in the tasks completed queue. You can wrap the check to the tasks completed queue with the tqdm progress bar. I am not putting the implementation of the do_work() function here, it is not relevant, as the message here is to monitor the tasks completed queue and update the progress bar every time a result is in.

```
def par_proc(job_list, num_cpus=None, verbose=False):

# Get the number of cores
if not num_cpus:
    num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)

print('* Parallel processing')
print('* Running on {} cores'.format(num_cpus))

# Set-up the queues for sending and receiving data to/from the workers
tasks_pending = mp.Queue()
tasks_completed = mp.Queue()

# Gather processes and results here
processes = []
results = []

# Count tasks
num_tasks = 0

# Add the tasks to the queue
for job in job_list:
    for task in job['tasks']:
        expanded_job = {}
        num_tasks = num_tasks + 1
        expanded_job.update({'func': pickle.dumps(job['func'])})
        expanded_job.update({'task': task})
        tasks_pending.put(expanded_job)

# Set the number of workers here
num_workers = min(num_cpus, num_tasks)

# We need as many sentinels as there are worker processes so that ALL processes exit when there is no more
# work left to be done.
for c in range(num_workers):
    tasks_pending.put(SENTINEL)

print('* Number of tasks: {}'.format(num_tasks))

# Set-up and start the workers
for c in range(num_workers):
    p = mp.Process(target=do_work, args=(tasks_pending, tasks_completed, verbose))
    p.name = 'worker' + str(c)
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

# Gather the results
completed_tasks_counter = 0

with tqdm(total=num_tasks) as bar:
    while completed_tasks_counter < num_tasks:
        results.append(tasks_completed.get())
        completed_tasks_counter = completed_tasks_counter + 1
        bar.update(completed_tasks_counter)

for p in processes:
    p.join()

return results
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on "user17242583" answer, I created the following function. It should be as fast as Pool.map and the results are always ordered. Plus, you can pass as many parameters to your function as you want and not just a single iterable.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
from tqdm import tqdm


def imap_tqdm(function, iterable, processes, chunksize=1, desc=None, disable=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Run a function in parallel with a tqdm progress bar and an arbitrary number of arguments.
    Results are always ordered and the performance should be the same as of Pool.map.
    :param function: The function that should be parallelized.
    :param iterable: The iterable passed to the function.
    :param processes: The number of processes used for the parallelization.
    :param chunksize: The iterable is based on the chunk size chopped into chunks and submitted to the process pool as separate tasks.
    :param desc: The description displayed by tqdm in the progress bar.
    :param disable: Disables the tqdm progress bar.
    :param kwargs: Any additional arguments that should be passed to the function.
    """
    if kwargs:
        function_wrapper = partial(_wrapper, function=function, **kwargs)
    else:
        function_wrapper = partial(_wrapper, function=function)

    results = [None] * len(iterable)
    with Pool(processes=processes) as p:
        with tqdm(desc=desc, total=len(iterable), disable=disable) as pbar:
            for i, result in p.imap_unordered(function_wrapper, enumerate(iterable), chunksize=chunksize):
                results[i] = result
                pbar.update()
    return results


def _wrapper(enum_iterable, function, **kwargs):
    i = enum_iterable[0]
    result = function(enum_iterable[1], **kwargs)
    return i, result
```

Answer (score 1):

`tqdm` has released its own simple, elegant [APIs](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/contrib.concurrent/) for concurrent.

I give the following snippet as a straightforward example to illustrate multi-threading.

```
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import thread_map

def f(row):
    x, y = row
    time.sleep(1)  # to visualize the progress

thread_map(f, [(x, y) for x, y in zip(range(1000), range(1000))])
```

Answer (score -3):

This approach simple and it works.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

def job():
    time.sleep(1)
    pbar.update()

pool = ThreadPool(5)
with tqdm(total=100) as pbar:
    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(job)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```