# Use tqdm with concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures, tqdm

I have a multithreaded function that I would like a status bar for using `tqdm`. Is there an easy way to show a status bar with `ThreadPoolExecutor`? It is the parallelization part that is confusing me.

```
import concurrent.futures

def f(x):
    return f**2

my_iter = range(1000000)

def run(f,my_iter):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        function = list(executor.map(f, my_iter))
    return results

run(f, my_iter) # wrap tqdr around this function?
```

Comment: you can use `from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920124/multiprocessing-use-tqdm-to-display-a-progress-bar/59905309#59905309

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can wrap `tqdm` around  the `executor` as the following  to track the progress:

`list(tqdm(executor.map(f, iter), total=len(iter))`

Here is your example:

```
import time  
import concurrent.futures
from tqdm import tqdm

def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.001)  # to visualize the progress
    return x**2

def run(f, my_iter):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = list(tqdm(executor.map(f, my_iter), total=len(my_iter)))
    return results

my_iter = range(100000)
run(f, my_iter)
```

And the result is like this:

```
16%|██▏           | 15707/100000 [00:00<00:02, 31312.54it/s]
```

Comment: Thank you! The key seems to be the list() around tqdm, why is that the case?

Comment: @DreamFlasher: That behavior is because tqdm runs on execution. Executor.map itself is only a generator.

Comment: Like that, you will not get the output instantly ! so you've to wait until the full progress completed till you see the full result !

Comment: the `total` argument in tqdm is important. Without it, we can not see the overall progress.

Comment: This blocks time updates in the progress bar, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Just call update(0) to update the time

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No progress bar shows at all. I have to put `tqdm` into the function I'm running which results in one progress bar for each process.

Comment: To get ordered results as they come in (and update the tqdm accordingly), use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.imap` instead of `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.map` (which has some [caveats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map)).

Answer (score 85):

The problem with the accepted answer is that the `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` function is obliged to generate results not in the order that they become available. So if the first invocation of `myfunc` happens to be, for example, the last one to complete, the progress bar will go from 0% to 100% all at once and only when all of the calls have completed. Much better would be to use `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` with `as_completed`:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
from tqdm import tqdm

def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.001)  # to visualize the progress
    return x**2

def run(f, my_iter):
    l = len(my_iter)
    with tqdm(total=l) as pbar:
        # let's give it some more threads:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            futures = {executor.submit(f, arg): arg for arg in my_iter}
            results = {}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                arg = futures[future]
                results[arg] = future.result()
                pbar.update(1)
    print(321, results[321])

my_iter = range(100000)
run(f, my_iter)
```

Prints:

```
321 103041
```

This is just the general idea. Depending upon the type of `my_iter`, it may not be possible to directly take apply the `len` function directly to it without first converting it into a list. The main point is to use `submit` with `as_completed`.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped but out of some reason the progress bar stopped after a while?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that with minor modifications (move to `def main()`) this works just as well with the [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor), which can be much faster if `f(x)` actually does computation since it is not affected by the global interpreter lock.

Comment: Since someone just asked me, here is the code of the example adapted for the `ProcessPoolExecutor` https://gist.github.com/ltalirz/9220946c5c9fd920a1a2d81ce7375c47

Comment: @leopold.talirz Of course, if it weren't for the call to `sleep` that was added solely to "visualize the result", function `f` is really a poor candidate even for multiprocessing since it is not CPU-intensive enough to justify the added overhead (that is, just calling `f` in a loop would be faster). The real point of the question as I understood was really about how to update the progress bar.  But for what it's worth, with the call to `sleep`, multithreading does better than multiprocessing with *this particular f function* due to its reduced overhead.

Comment: This blocks time updates in the progress bar, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Just call update(0) to update the time

Comment: This is a good solution.  However, I have a problem where the progress bar does not update if the above `run` function is executed more than once in the same jupyter notebook instance.  Can anyone else confirm this problem and/or offer a solution?

Comment: Because it took me way too long to figure this out: make sure your `as_completed()` call is **inside** the executor context.. *facepalm*

Answer (score 6):

Most short way, i think:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(myfunc, range(len(my_array))), total=len(my_array)))
```

Answer (score 4):

tried the example but progress bar fails still, and I find [this post](https://techoverflow.net/2017/05/18/how-to-use-concurrent-futures-map-with-a-tqdm-progress-bar/), seems useful in short way to use:

```
def tqdm_parallel_map(fn, *iterables):
    """ use tqdm to show progress"""
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures_list = []
    for iterable in iterables:
        futures_list += [executor.submit(fn, i) for i in iterable]
    for f in tqdm(concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_list), total=len(futures_list)):
        yield f.result()


def multi_cpu_dispatcher_process_tqdm(data_list, single_job_fn):
    """ multi cpu dispatcher """
    output = []
    for result in tqdm_parallel_map(single_job_fn, data_list):
        output += result
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

I find more intuitive to use the `update()` method of `tqdm`, we keep an human readable structure:

```
with tqdm(total=len(mylist)) as progress:                         
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for __ in executor.map(fun, mylist):
            progress.update() # We update the progress bar each time that a job finish
```

Since I don't care about the output of `fun` I use `__` as throwaway variable.

Comment: In python _ is throwaway variable not __

Comment: @Emsi Every valid variable name can be a throwaway variable. Also python store the last returned value by the shell in `_`. This is sometime useful to debug a program, so I always use `__`.

Comment: by convention _ is used because it gets overwritten often and thus you do not risk it staying indefinitely and never garbage collected.  See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to the accepted answer:

```py
# works
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
   futures = executor.map(f, my_iter)
   result = list(tqdm(futures), total=len(my_iter))

# does NOT work (only updates at the very end)
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
   futures = executor.map(f, my_iter)
result = list(tqdm(futures), total=len(my_iter))
```

Makes sense, but I'm likely not the only having tried the second approach...