# Use tqdm with multiprocessing for multiple progress bars

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, tqdm, process-pool

I want to monitor progress across multiple workers which are different processes. For each subprocess I have its own progress bar but it doest work properly with `ProcessPoolExecutor` executor.

```
def main():
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=PROCESSES) as executor:
        fut_to_num = {}
        for i in range(PROCESSES):
            fut = executor.submit(execute_many_threads, i)
            fut_to_num[fut] = i

        for future in futures.as_completed(fut_to_num):
            r = future.result()
            # print('{} returned {}'.format(fut_to_num[future], r))
    print('\nDone!\n')


def execute_many_threads(n_pool=0):
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREADS) as executor:
        for i in range(THREADS):
            executor.submit(execute_thread, n_pool, i)
    return n_pool+1


def execute_thread(n_pool=0, n_thread=0):
    s = random.randint(1, 5)
    thread_num = n_pool*(PROCESSES-1) + n_thread

    progress = tqdm.tqdm(
        desc='#{:02d}'.format(thread_num),
        position=thread_num,
        total=10*s,
        leave=False,
    )
    # print('Executing {}: {}...'.format(thread_num, s))
    for i in range(s):
        time.sleep(1)
        progress.update(n=10)
    progress.close()
    return s
```

When replaced with `ThreadPoolExecutor` (second line) everything works properly, so I assume this might be related to some serialization issue. Could you please help figure out proper invocation of `tqdm` when using multiprocessing.

`python --version` is `Python 3.7.2` and `tqdm==4.31.1`, `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: may be this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601756/use-tqdm-with-concurrent-futures

Comment: @vigneshkrishnan no, this one works perfectly with threads, question is about multiprocessing

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920124/multiprocessing-use-tqdm-to-display-a-progress-bar