# Why do logging and futures not work together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

I tried the following script but the log does not work.

```
import time  
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import os

######## Logging ################
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join('logs','pipeline2.log'))
#In case we have also a StreamHandler with level of INFO
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.001)  # to visualize the progress
    logger.info(x**2)

def run(f, my_iter):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601756/use-tqdm-with-concurrent-futures
    """
    import concurrent.futures
    my_iter = list(my_iter)
    l = len(my_iter)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(f, arg): arg for arg in my_iter}
        results = {}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            arg = futures[future]
            results[arg] = future.result()

my_iter = range(10000)
run(f, my_iter)
```

When running the script: I do not see any file pipeline2.log which appears in the logs. How can I solve this issue?

Edit: as suggested i retrieve tqdm (i do not think it can interfer)n in the code so it could be easyly reproductible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: If your question is about futures and logging, why does your example include tdqm? That precludes others from testing your code if they don't have it installed. See [mre].

Comment: @mkrieger: i edited the question to explian what i mean .Moreover i wanted to test it with tqdm since process a lot of file (i put a toy fun and want to see the progress

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your code? I can think of the following situation the log does not work.

```py
import time  
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import os
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log_path = os.path.join('logs','pipeline2.log')

def add_file_handler(log_path):
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    print(f"handler fileno {file_handler.stream.fileno()} added")

def remove_file(filepath):
    print(f"{filepath} exists: {os.path.exists(filepath)}")
    try:
        print(f"{filepath} remove: {os.remove(filepath)}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.001)  # to visualize the progress
    logger.info(x**2)

def run(f, my_iter):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601756/use-tqdm-with-concurrent-futures
    """
    import concurrent.futures
    my_iter = list(my_iter)
    l = len(my_iter)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(f, arg): arg for arg in my_iter}
        results = {}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            arg = futures[future]
            results[arg] = future.result()
```

run

```py
remove_file(log_path)
add_file_handler(log_path)
remove_file(log_path)
my_iter = range(10)
run(f, my_iter)    

try:
    with open(log_path) as f:
        print(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"No such file or directory {log_path}")
```

print

```
logs/pipeline2.log exists: True
logs/pipeline2.log remove: None
handler fileno 58 added
logs/pipeline2.log exists: True
logs/pipeline2.log remove: None
No such file or directory logs/pipeline2.log
```

then run

```py
add_file_handler(log_path)
my_iter = range(10)
run(f, my_iter)    

for handler in logger.handlers:
    print(handler.stream.fileno())
    print(handler.stream.write(f"fileno: {handler.stream.fileno()}\n"))
    print(handler.stream.flush())
try:
    with open(log_path) as f:
        print(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"No such file or directory {log_path}")
```

output

```
handler fileno 61 added
58
11
None
61
11
None
2020-10-23 23:31:27,149:INFO:__main__:0
2020-10-23 23:31:27,149:INFO:__main__:1
2020-10-23 23:31:27,157:INFO:__main__:36
2020-10-23 23:31:27,155:INFO:__main__:16
2020-10-23 23:31:27,155:INFO:__main__:25
2020-10-23 23:31:27,156:INFO:__main__:9
2020-10-23 23:31:27,150:INFO:__main__:4
2020-10-23 23:31:27,159:INFO:__main__:64
2020-10-23 23:31:27,159:INFO:__main__:49
2020-10-23 2
```