Combine Async with Parallism
I have the following code:
async def run_task(...):
    ...
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(cfg.concurrency_limit)

    async def run_single_sample(task_sample: TaskSample):
        async with semaphore:
            await run_agent(cfg, task_sample, cfg.output_dir / task.value)

    samples = [run_single_sample(task_sample) for task_sample in sliced_samples]
    await tqdm.gather(*samples, desc=f"Task: {task.value}")

It is part of a ML application. So imagine run_agent being some async chat system, where LLMs solve a problem. In this process multiple API calls are made to OpenAI, to some local modals and also a little bit CPU processes for executing local code.
While the async / blocking stuff makes sense for the API calls, I am not sure it makes sense for the CPU processes. Because it is my understanding that everything is still sequential. E.g. while sample 1 might wait for an CPU call, sample 2 begins, but then sample 1 continues again.
Looking at my htop output, it seems it uses 1 cpu 100%, so I figured maybe due to code local execution within the agent run, CPU might be a bottleneck here.
Thus I tried combining it with something like ThreadPoolExecutor, asyncio.to_thread, asyncio.run_in_executor, ...
but all of them are for running sync methods it seems.
How could I do it correctly? Or is my use case somehow flawed.

A concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor is absolutely not for running  methods synchronously. The concurrent.futures API lets you submit tasks to be executed in a separate thread. Maybe update your question to show us what you've tried.

@larsks No, I meant (maybe it was unclear) that it is for running sync methods, not for running them synchronously. Or to put it the other way around, it is not for running async methods (methods defined with the async keyword, like my run_task method or the run_agent method)

As for showing what I tried: Many things, but none worked and I do not have the code anymore. But one example might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242947. As can be seen f is a sync method, whereas my run_agent is async and during execution I got an error as I did not await it. The same problem with asyncio.run_in_executor for instance. asyncio.run() might work, but I always got problems with closing event loops, even without using Threads. Somewhere I read that you best call that method once in the beginning.

Are you saying that the async run_agent(...) coroutine is using a lot of CPU cycles? If it is  and it uses run_in_executor for the CPU-bound calls, it should be using a ProcessPoolExecutor. Your really nee to post an [mre] because I have no idea what you are executing.

@Booboo Yeah exaclty. I guess that is also the answer of Richard. I use the autogen framework that does most of the work, so their is not too much control over the code I have. I have not analysed in detail where exactly the cpu usage is coming from (maybe I should), but I figured just letting the whole method run in a thread seems to most straight forward thing ... apparently not.

It seems like you're understanding is largely correct, the issue lies here:

In this process multiple API calls are made to OpenAI, to some local modals and also a little bit CPU processes for executing local code.

You have to break out the parts of run_agent that use cpu or gpu into discrete, sync-flavored functions and run them in threads or processes with e.g. await run_in_executor(...). If you aren't able to refactor the async function in this way then you will be out of luck until someone writes a multi threaded event loop!

Thanks for the answer! I figured something like that. Not sure if I can easily find out what eats up my cpu as I use a framework quite heavily that might generate this. I just thought using threads for my whole async function would be much simpler as I can gain significant speed ups without investing the real issue. I will leave this question open for a bit, maybe someone has still an idea for the multi threaded event loop. Otherwise I accept your answer. Cheers!
