# Adding a ProgressBar to a multithreaded Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i am trying to add a progressbar  to my script but i couldn't succeed because i think it is multi-threaded or maybe it should be added  in a separate thread . i found plenty of solutions in stackoverflow , for example tqdm library but i couldn't implement it  , also i think i have a confusion where exactly i have to implement the progress bar code to make it works.

this is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# !/usr/bin/python
import  codecs
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

start_raw = "myfile"
threads = 10

with codecs.open(start_raw, mode='r', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as f:
    lists = f.read().splitlines()
    lists = list((lists))


def myfunction(x):
    try:
        print x

    except:
        pass


def Main():
    try:
        pp = Pool(int(threads))
        pr = pp.map(myfunction, lists)


    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

i have tried this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276885/9746396 :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# !/usr/bin/python
import  codecs
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import tqdm

start_raw = "myfile"
threads = 1

with codecs.open(start_raw, mode='r', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as f:
    lists = f.read().splitlines()
    lists = list((lists))


def myfunction(x):
    try:
        print (x)

    except:
        pass

def Main():
    try:
        pp = Pool(int(threads))
        pr = pp.map(myfunction, lists)


    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2) as p:
        r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(Main(), range(30)), total=30))
```

but code does not run and i get exception (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable)

```
0%|                                                                                           | 0/30 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 35, in <module>
    r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(Main(), range(30)), total=30))
  File "C:\mypath\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1118, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "C:\mypath\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 865, in next
    raise value
  File "C:\mypath\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
  0%|                                                                                           | 0/30 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiprocessing : use tqdm to display a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920124/multiprocessing-use-tqdm-to-display-a-progress-bar)

Comment: no sir , i have tryed to implement but almost all of the solutions not working

Comment: Could you please be more specific, what exactly in the solution above fails for you?

Comment: i have posted an update about what i tried to implement

Answer (score 0):

I presume you wanted to pass `myfunction` instead of `Main` to `imap`, consistently with the first example.

When you pass `Main()` to `p.imap` in `r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(Main(), range(30)), total=30))`, Python calls executes `Main` method and passes the return value as the first argument to `imap`.

You should remove the parentheses after `Main` as: `p.imap` in `r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(Main, range(30)), total=30))`.

Comment: i have already tried that and i get this exception TypeError: Main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @TaibAdhibi I've edited the answer, does it work with replacing `Main` with `myfunction`?

Comment: i have the same exception if you could try the program and post the solution ( full code )