# Downloading multiple urls with threadpool

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

I having problem downloading multiple urls.
My code still only download 1 url per session. Still need to finish the first one before downloading the next one.

I want to download like 3 urls at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0'
}

def download(path, video_url, bar: tqdm):
    
    res = requests.get(video_url, headers, stream=True)

    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for b in res.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(b)
            bar.update(len(b))

def get_length(video_url):
    res = requests.get(video_url, headers, stream=True)
    le = int(res.headers['Content-Length'])
    return le

def download_all(urls: list, thread: int = cpu_count()):

    total = len(urls)
    count = 0

    pool = ThreadPool(thread)  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528204/14951175

    for url in urls:
        output_file = get_url_path(url)
        count += 1
        content_length = get_length(video_url=url)
        with tqdm(total=content_length, unit='B', ncols=(150-1), desc=f'Downloading {count} of {total}', unit_divisor=1024, ascii=True, unit_scale=True) as bar:
            pool.apply_async(download(output_file, url, bar))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


  urls = read_lines('urls.txt')
  download_all(urls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```py
pool.apply_async(download(output_file, url, bar))
```

must be

```py
pool.apply_async(download, (output_file, url, bar))
```

Otherwise you call the `download` method instead of passing it (and the args) to the ThreadPool.

---

**Edit**

Use `starmap` to map the urls to `func` where you perform the download (btw: you can safe the duplicate get-request). And add the `position` argument.
To be honest, the bars don't works very smooth, but I don't really have experience with `tqdm` or `ThreadPool`. But in general the downloads seem to work.

```
def download_all(urls: list, thread: int = cpu_count()):
    total = len(urls)

    pool = ThreadPool(thread)

    def func(count, url):
        output_file = get_url_path(url)
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
        content_length = int(req.headers['Content-Length'])
        with tqdm(total=content_length, unit='B', desc=f'Downloading {count + 1} of {total}',
                  unit_divisor=1024, ascii=True, unit_scale=True, position=count, file=sys.stdout) as bar:
            with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
                for b in req.iter_content(1024):
                    f.write(b)
                    bar.update(len(b))

    pool.starmap(func, enumerate(urls))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Oh wait I'm gonna test it now. Thank you

Comment: still doesn't work and progressbar also not showing

Downloading 1 of 3:   0%|                    | 0.00/460k [00:00<?, ?B/s]

Comment: Oh wow it worked. However there's just a little problem. 
at the end of the download, it's duplicating the last line
Like this screenshot
https://i.imgur.com/DcBaKsA.png

But I already accepted your answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort

Comment: Unfortunately, I have also faced this effect. Maybe this is a windows problem, although according to the [FAQ](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues) it should work with `ascii=True`. Honestly I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: It's ok. I just use a custom simple progressbar instead.