# join() output from multiprocessing when using tqdm for progress bar

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I'm using a construct similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921948) to run my processing in parallel with a progress bar courtesy of `tqdm`...

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from tqdm import *

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   return square 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        max_ = 30
        with tqdm(total=max_) as pbar:
            for _ in p.imap_unordered(_foo, range(0, max_)):
                pbar.update()
    results = p.join()  ## My attempt to combine results
```

`results` is always `NoneType` though, and I can not work out how to get my results combined. I understand that `with ...:` will close what it is working with on completion automatically.

I've tried doing away with the outer `with:`

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_ = 10
    p = Pool(processes=8)
    with tqdm(total=max_) as pbar:
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(_foo, range(0, max_)):
            pbar.update()
    p.close()
    results = p.join()
    print(f"Results : {results}")
```

Stumped as to how to `join()` my results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `p.join()` just waits for all the pool processes to end and returns `None`. This call is actually unnecessary since you are using the pool as a context manager, that is you have specified `with Pool(processes=2) as p:`). When that block terminates an implicit call is made to `p.terminate()`, which immediately terminates the pool processes and any tasks that may be running or queued up to run (there are none in your case).

It is, in fact, iterating the *iterator* returned by the call to `p.imap_unordered` that returns each return value from your worker function, `_foo`. But since you are using method `imap_unordered`, the results returned may not be in submission order. In other words, you cannot assume that the return values will be in succession 0, 1, , 4, 9, etc. There are many ways to  handle this, such as having your worker function return the original argument along with the squared value:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from tqdm import *

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   return my_number, square # return the argunent along with the result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        max_ = 30
        results = [None] * 30; # preallocate the resulys array
        with tqdm(total=max_) as pbar:
            for x, result in p.imap_unordered(_foo, range(0, max_)):
                results[x] = result
                pbar.update()
        print(results)
```

The second way is to not use `imap_unordered`, but rather `apply_async` with a callback function. The disadvantage of this is that for large iterables you do not have the option of specifying a *chunksize* argument as you do with `imap_unordered`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from tqdm import *

def _foo(my_number):
   square = my_number * my_number
   return square

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def my_callback(_): # ignore result
        pbar.update() # update progress bar when a result is produced

    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        max_ = 30
        with tqdm(total=max_) as pbar:
            async_results = [p.apply_async(_foo, (x,), callback=my_callback) for x in range(0, max_)]
            # wait for all tasks to complete:
            p.close()
            p.join()
            results = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
        print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I knew that `with Pool(processes = 2) as p:` was terminated for me had failed to understand at what point I was iterating over my list and could access the results. In hindsight it seems so obvious.