# Parallel processing with Python class object

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, parallel-processing, scipy

I have a for loop in Python that contains an optimization function [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html). The function [outputs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult) a class object (called `sol`) that describes the optimized results:

```
import numpy as np           
import scipy.optimize as so

def root2d(x,a,b):
   F1 = np.exp(-np.exp(-(x[0]+x[1]))) - x[1]*(b+x[0]**2)
   F2 = x[0]*np.cos(x[1]) + x[1]*np.sin(x[0]) - a
   return (F1,F2)

x0 = np.array([0.1,0.1]) # initial guess
alist = np.linspace(-0.5,-0.3,10)
blist = np.linspace(0.2,0.3,10)

xlist = np.zeros(10)
ylist = np.zeros(10)
zlist = np.zeros(10)

for jj in range(0,10):

    a = alist[jj]
    b = blist[jj]

    sol = so.root(root2d,x0,args=(a,b),method='lm',tol=1e-9)

    xlist[jj] = sol.x[0] # optimised value
    ylist[jj] = sol.x[1] # optimised value
    zlist[jj] = sol.success # was solver successful?

# do something with xlist ylist zlist
```

Now I'm trying to parallelize the `for` loop using the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop). However I'm not sure how to deal with the `sol` outputs and how to write the above `for` loop so that it can be used in this kind of structure:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(4)
xlist,ylist,zlist = zip(*p.map(so.root,range(0,10)))
```

which was given as an answer by Nolen Royalty.

**Edit:** I want to run my program (no this MWE) on a HPC cluster where the available Python modules are numpy, scipy, matplotlib, cython and mpi4py. Although there are numerous methods to do parallel processing, I want to make minimal changes to my existing (serial for loops) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Pool`,  you typcially provide a function and call `Pool.map` on it.

In your case:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run(jj):
    import scipy.optimize as so

    a = alist[jj]
    b = blist[jj]

    sol = so.root(root2d,x0,args=(a,b),method='lm',tol=1e-9)

    return sol.x[0], sol.x[1], sol.success


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # your declarations go here ...

    p = Pool(4)
    result = p.map(run, range(0,10))
```

... which gives you a list of tuples, containing the solutions...

Comment: Should `x0`, `alist`, `blist` be inside the `run(jj)` function? And the `xlist = ylist = zlist = np.zeros(10)` should be just before `p=Pool(4)` I assume

Comment: Nope. All those definitions, including the function definition of ``root2d`` go where I put ``# your declarations go here``

Comment: Strange... I just get an error when I do that: `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'`

Comment: which version of python are you using? For me (Python3) this code runs without errors... Did you create the pool (``p = Pool(4)``) inside the ``if __name__ == '__main__'`` as stated above? Where did you put the ``import numpy as np``?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 64bit. Yes I create the parallel pool inside `if __name__ == '__main__'`. The `import numpy as np` comes before I import `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Not possible to **exactly** run your code, but I have copied and pasted everything you mentioned at `# your declarations go here` and put the `import numpy` at the very top before I call the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: yeah what I meant was whether you had a different 'local' code which you could not share publicly.

Comment: No local code. I'm just trying to figure out this MWE, so what you see here is what I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

The code given in Tw UxTLi51Nus's post doesn't appear to work on Python 3.5.2 for some reason. With some changes, the following code appears ok...

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.optimize as so
from multiprocessing import Pool

def root2d(x,a,b):
    F1 = np.exp(-np.exp(-(x[0]+x[1]))) - x[1]*(b+x[0]**2)
    F2 = x[0]*np.cos(x[1]) + x[1]*np.sin(x[0]) - a
    return (F1,F2)

def run(jj):

    x0 = np.array([0.1,0.1]) # initial guess
    alist = np.linspace(-0.5,-0.3,10)
    blist = np.linspace(0.2,0.3,10)

    a = alist[jj]
    b = blist[jj]

    sol = so.root(root2d,x0,args=(a,b),method='lm',tol=1e-9)

    return sol.x[0], sol.x[1], sol.success


if __name__ == '__main__':

    xlist = np.zeros(10)
    ylist = np.zeros(10)
    zlist = np.zeros(10)

    p = Pool(4)
    result = p.map(run, range(0,10))
    print(result)
```

I've had to put the iterated values `alist`, `blist`, and initial guess `x0` inside the `run` function. These are fed into the `scipy.optimize.root` solver. There are no errors when I do this, and the solutions are:

```
[(-0.53888782445459149, 0.043495493090149454, True),
 (-0.52328348126598456, 0.032937536902490253, True), 
 (-0.50743370799474086, 0.022462155879391384, True), 
 (-0.49135105437855231, 0.01203948230426068, True), 
 (-0.47502920008575156, 0.001732198125265777, True), 
 (-0.45846822054716679, -0.0084225504551842089, True), 
 (-0.4416527225847745, -0.018336039419045602, True), 
 (-0.42455931996843449, -0.027893297385455082, True), 
 (-0.40720848051853215, -0.037005663686040566, True), 
 (-0.38955545334271019, -0.045486751099290013, True)]
```

Comment: well I do not get it why there is that difference, on my system it runs perfectly fine when ``x0``, ``alist`` and ``blist`` are declared between the declaration of ``xlist`` and ``if __name__ == '__main__'``

Comment: you can even delete the declarations of ``xlist``, ``ylist`` and ``zlist`` as the results are now in ``result`` BTW