# Printed output not displayed when using joblib in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, joblib

So I am using [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) to parallelize some code and I noticed that I couldn't print things when using it inside a jupyter notebook.

I tried using doing the same example in ipython and it worked perfectly.

Here is a minimal (not) working example to write in a jupyter notebook cell

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(print)(i) for i in range(10))
```

So I am getting the output as `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` but nothing is printed.

What I expect to see (print order could be random in reality):

```py
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

### Note:

You can see the prints in the logs of the notebook process. But I would like the prints to happen in the notebook, not the logs of the notebook process.

### EDIT

I have opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/402), but with minimal attention so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed in the latest version of `ipykernel`.
To solve the issue just do `pip install --upgrade ipykernel`.

From what I understand, any version above 6 will do, as mentioned in [this Github comment](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/402#issuecomment-877717039) by one of the maintainers.

Answer (score 17):

I think this caused in part by the way `Parallel` spawns the child workers, and how Jupyter Notebook handles IO for those workers. When started without specifying a value for `backend`, `Parallel` will default to [`loky`](https://pypi.org/project/loky/) which utilizes a pooling strategy that directly uses a fork-exec model to create the subprocesses.

If you start Notebook from a terminal using

```
$ jupyter-notebook
```

the regular `stderr` and `stdout` streams appear to remain attached to that terminal, while the notebook session will start in a new browser window. Running the posted code snippet in the notebook *does* produce the expected output, but it seems to go to `stdout` and ends up in the terminal (as hinted in the **Note** in the question). This further supports the suspicion that this behavior is caused by the interaction between `loky` and notebook, and the way the standard IO streams are handled by notebook for child processes.

This lead me to [this discussion](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/700#issuecomment-583612357) on github (active within the past 2 weeks as of this posting) where the authors of notebook appear to be aware of this, but it would seem that there is no obvious and quick fix for the issue at the moment.

If you don't mind switching the backend that `Parallel` uses to spawn children, you can do so like this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=8, backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(print)(i) for i in range(10))
```

with the `multiprocessing` backend, things work as expected. `threading` looks to work fine too. This may not be the solution you were hoping for, but hopefully it is sufficient while the notebook authors work on finding a proper solution.

I'll cross-post this to GitHub in case anyone there cares to add to this answer (I don't want to misstate anyone's intent or put words in people mouths!).

---

Test Environment:
MacOS - Mojave (10.14)
Python - 3.7.3
pip3 - 19.3.1

Tested in 2 configurations. Confirmed to produce the expected output when using both `multiprocessing` and `threading` for the `backend` parameter. Packages install using `pip3`.

Setup 1:

```
ipykernel                               5.1.1
ipython                                 7.5.0
jupyter                                 1.0.0
jupyter-client                          5.2.4
jupyter-console                         6.0.0
jupyter-core                            4.4.0
notebook                                5.7.8
```

Setup 2:

```
ipykernel                               5.1.4
ipython                                 7.12.0
jupyter                                 1.0.0
jupyter-client                          5.3.4
jupyter-console                         6.1.0
jupyter-core                            4.6.2
notebook                                6.0.3
```

I also was successful using the same versions as 'Setup 2' but with the `notebook` package version downgraded to 6.0.2.

#### Note:

This approach works inconsistently on Windows. Different combinations of software versions yield different results. Doing the most intuitive thing-- upgrading everything to the latest version-- does not guarantee it will work.

Comment: I can confirm this works in Colab, however I just tested with Jupyter Notebook v6.0.2 and JupyterLab v1.2.4 (Python v3.6.8), and it doesn't work on neither, I just see the prints in stdout and get the array of None returned. What version of Jupyter Notebook are you using?

Comment: Your solution also works when testing with online Jupyter Notebook v5.7.8 (python 3.6.7) and JupyterLab v1.0.10, so might be related to a specific version.

Comment: I updated the answer to include details on the test environment. I got the expected results using both versions of Notebook you mentioned, in addition to 6.0.3. I am on Python 3.7, but I would be somewhat surprised if that was the issue. How are you installing packages? Are you using MacOS/Linux, or are you on Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows, that actually could be the difference.

Comment: I confirm it is working on Linux. I guess we found another bug related to Windows only. Please update your answer to mention that. 
Thanks for your help, this issue caused me a lot of headache! :-)

Comment: any progress on fixes for windows users?  can confirm that neither 'multiprocessing' or 'threading' backends work on windows 10 using jupyter notebook, python 3.6, and anaconda

Comment: @spizwhiz actually just checked on this yesterday. Unfortunately, the threads on GitHub where this issue was being discussed have not seen much activity since February, so I doubt there will be a fix in the immediate future.

Comment: @Z4-tier  Thanks.  Do I understand correctly that I would run into the same issues if I tried to use multiprocessing directly?

Comment: @spizwhiz If you directly import `multiprocessing` and implement your own pipelining solution, you can probably get around this problem (but that will be a lot of work, with it's own set of new problems). You might even be able to get around it by reconfiguring `joblib` to use a different parallelization library on the back end (either `multiprocessing` or `threading`). It's worth a shot, since it's a quick change if you already have everything ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

In Z4-tier's git link scottgigante's method work in Windows, but opposite to the mentined results: in Jupyter notebook, the "multiprocessing" backend hang forever, but the default loky work well (python 3.8.5 and notebook 6.1.1):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import sys
def g(x):
    stream = getattr(sys, "stdout")
    print("{}".format(x), file=stream)
    stream.flush()
    return x
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(g)(x**2) for x in range(5))

executed in 91ms, finished 11:17:25 2021-05-13
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

A simpler method is to use the identity function in delay:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(lambda y:y)([np.log(x),np.sin(x)]) for x in range(5))
executed in 151ms, finished 09:34:18 2021-05-17
[[-inf, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.8414709848078965],
 [0.6931471805599453, 0.9092974268256817],
 [1.0986122886681098, 0.1411200080598672],
 [1.3862943611198906, -0.7568024953079282]]
```

Or use like this:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(lambda y:[np.log(y),np.sin(y)])(x) for x in range(5))
executed in 589ms, finished 09:44:57 2021-05-17
[[-inf, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.8414709848078965],
 [0.6931471805599453, 0.9092974268256817],
 [1.0986122886681098, 0.1411200080598672],
 [1.3862943611198906, -0.7568024953079282]]
```