# Print the output of a function in joblib

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to use `joblib` to parallelize a loop that runs over a function. I want the intermediate `print` commands of the function to be displayed, not just the `return` value of the function.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def dummy(i):
    print("the value passed is",i)

Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(dummy)(i) for i in range(0,5,1))
```

I get the following output:

```
[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None]
```

I want to get the following output (or something similar):

```
[the value passed is 0,
the value passed is 1,
the value passed is 2,
the value passed is 3,
the value passed is 4]
```

Edit: 
I just noticed that it does indeed print my required output in the terminal window from which my Jupyter notebook is launched. Any ideas on how to actually `print` it in my notebook. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printed output not displayed when using joblib in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955330/printed-output-not-displayed-when-using-joblib-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score -3):

> ```
> from joblib import Parallel, delayed
>
> def dummy(i):
>     return "the value passed is " + str(i)
>
> Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(dummy)(i) for i in range(0,5,1))
> ```

output::

```
[the value passed is 0,
the value passed is 1,
the value passed is 2,
the value passed is 3,
the value passed is 4]
```