# Print statement in cross-validation on custom estimator in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have build a custom estimator in sklearn, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html). Inside the `fit` method, I have a print statement, which I use for debugging. When I create an instance of this model and call the fit method, everything is working as expected. However, when calling `cross_val_score`, the statements are not printed anymore, although as far as I know, cross_val_score calls the `fit` method at each fold.
Is there any way to force the print statement inside cross-validation?

Comment: Could parallel processing be swallowing the output?  Try with n_jobs=1?

Comment: @BenReiniger yes, that was indeed the case. Thank your for your answer. So, is there any way I could prevent parallel processing from doing so?

Comment: are you running this in a Jupyter notebook, or ...?

Comment: yes, in a Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel processing in sklearn is handled by `joblib`.  When running `cross_val_score` with `n_jobs != 1`, evidently that doesn't play nicely with Jupyter output:
[Printed output not displayed when using joblib in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55955330/10495893)