# Filling pandas Data Frame

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a list of ticker values

```
ticker = ["AAPL","MSFT","GOOG"]
```

and I want to create a DF with "high" values of prices for all the stocks in the ticker list.

Creating an empty DF:

```
high_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ticker)
```

Filling the DF:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2010,2,1)

for each_column in high_df.columns:
   high_df[each_column] = web.DataReader(each_column, "yahoo",start,end)["High"]
```

This works but takes a long time if the ticker list is huge. Any other suggestions for approaches to speed up? Speed up with the way the DF is filled.

Comment: This is related to your api call

Comment: @WeNYoBen. Yes, but my question was more like can we speed up with parallelizing for loop with apply or something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like just need parallel computing.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def yourfunc(tic):
    start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 1)
    result=web.DataReader(tic, "yahoo", start, end)["High"]
    return result

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=verbosity_level, backend="threading")(
             map(delayed(yourfunc), ticker ))
```

About the conversion , you can using `pd.DataFrame(results,columns=ticker)`

Comment: Cool. I will test it now.