# parallelizing 'for' loop in Python 3

Tags: python-3.6

I am working with face recognition.
I am take user face and compare his face with users faces foto in my database but to do that

Since its a lot of data to handle, the process is very slow and I was considering parallelizing it. I tried doing something with joblib, but I have not been able to do it.
please help me to parallelizing my code

```
def is_matchT(snap,users):
    known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(snap)
    biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)
    i=0
    for user in users:
       unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(user)
       i=i+1
       unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)
       if len(biden_encoding)>0:
          for x in range(len(biden_encoding)):
              biden_encoding1 = biden_encoding[x]
              unknown_encoding = unknown_encoding[0]
              results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding1], unknown_encoding)
              if results[0]==True:
                  return user                
    else:
        return ' No faces in foto'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop)

Comment: but I cant do my code like this can you help me please AlexLarionov

Comment: Separate the code for processing one user in another function, then use the accepted answer the similar way