# Python: when is multiprocessing/threading/asyncio even possible? Can my function be calculated in parallel?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I implemented some logic (**on Windows 10**) creating a vector representing simulated spot prices based on numpy random variables. At the end of the day I need 10, 100 or 1000 of this vector. Using a simple for-loop generating 1000 of these, calculation needs roughly 160 seconds. I tried all possible ways of parallelization, e.g. found  [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop) and beyond. Some methods did not even work, others had no effect at all. So either:

1. the implementation of these parallelization tools were wrong ...
2. ... or my function can't be parallelized (because it already uses all threads the the cpu???)

Here is my function (`mrm`, `mp` and `spm` are my custom modules):

```
def tt(i):
    random_variables = np.random.standard_normal((3, I))
    mean_reversion_model = mrm.Model(t, m, random_variables, vola, df_regression_param, 
        df_mean_reversion_param)
    year_price_simulation = mp.Simulation(mean_reversion_model, df_initial_price)

    year_prices = year_price_simulation.prices()
    monthly_prices = mp.MonthlyPrices(year_prices, monthly_factors_file="month_factors_mr.csv", 
        date_today=date_today, years_to_future=years_to_future, debug=False)

    df_S_monthly = monthly_prices.get_monthly_prices()

    spot_price_simulation = spm.SpotPrice(jumps, mr_regression, 1., 365, 0.0, df_S_monthly, 
        verbose=False)
    res = spot_price_simulation.get_simulated_spot_prices()
    # result_dict[i] = res  # only needed using the multiprocessing examples
    return res
```

And these were my attempts (all come after)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

#### multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing

N = 10
MAX_WORKERS = 4
t0 = time.time()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=MAX_WORKERS)
t = pool.map(tt, range(N))  # dictionary in function is used to collect results
pool.close()
pool.join()
t1 = time.time() - t0
print("Elapsed time: {}s".format(t1))
```

-> won't come back...

#### multiprocessing.pool

```
import multiprocessing.pool
N = 100
MAX_WORKERS = 4
t0 = time.time()
with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=MAX_WORKERS) as pool:
    t = pool.map(tt, range(N))  # dictionary in function is used to collect results
t1 = time.time() - t0
print("Elapsed time: {}s".format(t1))
```

-> no improvement, same calculation time as for-loop

#### concurrent.futures

```
import concurrent.futures

N = 100
result_dict = dict().fromkeys(range(N))
MAX_WORKERS = 4
t0 = time.time()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for idx, out in enumerate(executor.map(tt, range(N))):
        result_dict[idx] = out
t1 = time.time() - t0
print("Elapsed time: {}s".format(t1))
```

-> no improvement, same calculation time as for-loop

#### asyncio

```
import asyncio

def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

N = 10
result_dict = dict().fromkeys(range(N))
MAX_WORKERS = 4
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    result_dict[i] = tt()
t1 = time.time() - t0
print("Elapsed time: {}s".format(t1))
```

-> Error: asyncio await wasn't used with future

#### numpy apply method

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
test = np.zeros((N, 1))
t0 = time.time()
res = np.apply_along_axis(tt, 1, test)
t1 = time.time() - t0
print("Elapsed time: {}s".format(t1))
```

-> no improvement

Comment: Have you tried adding the third argument to map, "chunksize"? Set it to 100 or so.

Comment: Not yet, will try it and report. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading doesn't really work for Python code because of the global interpreter lock: only one thread at a time can manipulate Python objects. You can use multithreading for calls to non-Python functions.

So you have to use multiprocessing.Pool instead. But in Windows, you must make your main code block conditional, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=MAX_WORKERS)
    ...etc...
```

otherwise, each worker will also attempt to startup a Pool and your system will hang. In Linux, this is not necessary, because it handles the creation of workers differently.

Edit: it seems that you did that.

Another thing to be aware of is that numpy in Anaconda uses multi-threaded Intel MKL routines for many numpy and scipy functions - especially the ones operating on large arrays. In that case, attempting to do multithreading or multiprocessing will be counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I forgot to mention that I call all these methods in the main block. Will edit my post.

Comment: Your edit gives me a new hint. I will research more about numpy and parallelization and give an update. Thank you.

Comment: After doing some research (google: multiprocessing and numpy) it a solution doesn't seem trivial. As seen here, a solution would be to split a numpy array and use it as parameter for pool.map. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3ovezc/multiprocessing_with_numpy_arrays/
I will not follow this matter for this special case anymore. Thank you for your advices.