# Parallel processing in Python with input output file

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, bigdata

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
j = 0
k = 0
time_array = []
average_pa = []
for i in range(3600):
    time_array.append(j)
    average_pa.append(k)
    j += 0.1
time_array1 = tuple(time_array)
pa1 = 0.0
time1 = 0.0
chunk_size = 1000
for chunk in pd.read_csv("data_fiftydyne.txt", header=1, delimiter='\t', 
                         chunksize=chunk_size,
                        skip_blank_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False, keep_default_na=False):
    file2 = chunk.to_numpy()
    for jj in range(file2.shape[0]):
        time1 = file2[jj][9]
        if type(time1) == str:
            time1 = 362
        pa1 = file2[jj][11]
        ff = open("aver_pa_time_fiftydyne.csv", "a")
        ff.truncate(0)
        ff.seek(0)
        for ii in range(3600):
            if math.floor(10 * time_array1[ii]) == math.floor(float(10 * time1)):
                average_pa[ii] += pas1
                print(pa1)
                print(time1)
            ff.write(str(average_pa[ii]) + ',' + str(time_array1[ii]) + '\n')
        ff.close()
```

This is code works in serial. How to parallelize this code? The size of the file is 67GB. It takes 5 days to run in series on CPU with 4.2GHz and 8GB RAM.

Comment: How do you know it takes 5 days for a parallel run if you're asking how to parallelize the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop)

Comment: Give us a few sample lines of your input file. Also, please explain in plain English, what you're trying to do. I see many inefficiencies in this code, and without knowing your objective, it is impossible for me to optimize your code for you