# Efficiently find strings in list of lists of strings (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, performance, find

I'm looking for an **efficient** way to find different strings in a list of string lists and return their indices.  Here is the code:

```
inp = [ 'ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3' ]
output = [ [ 'aaa', 'ans1', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ans2', 'ddd' ],
           [ 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ans2', 'ddd', 'ans1', 'aaa' ],
           [ 'ddd', 'ccc', 'ans2', 'ans1', 'aaa', 'bbb' ] ]

# expected result
# result = [ [ 1, 4, 3 ], [ 4, 2, 2 ], [ -1, -1, -1 ] ]
```

Those reported in the result are the indices for the position in the `output` list of each string in the `inp` list. For example, `ans2` is at index 4 in the first sublist, index 2 in the second sublist, and index 2 in the third sublist. Similarly for `ans1`. `ans3`, however, does not appear in any sublist and, therefore, the returned index is `-1`.

What I'm looking for is an **efficient** way to do this computation (*possibly in parallel?*) while avoiding the classic for loops that this can clearly be done with.

Some considerations:

- `output` has shape equal to `[ len( inp ), L ]`, where `L` is the size of the dictionary. In this case `L = 5`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried the usual nested for loops to do so but I was looking for performances and that's what I asked for, since I sincerely do not know where to start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks! I'll give it a chance

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension:

```
result = [[o.index(s) if s in o else -1 for o in output] for s in inp]
print(result) # [[1, 4, 3], [4, 2, 2], [-1, -1, -1]]
```

Update:

Also it's probably not the best idea to store -1 as an index for strings, which are not presented in the output list. -1 is a valid index in Python, which may potentially lead to errors in the future if you plan to do something with indexes, stored in the result.

Comment: @not_speshal agreed, using variable "input" will lead to an error, fixed it in the post

Comment: It will actually NOT lead to an error. It's just bad practice.

Comment: Minor correction: The `//` should be `#`.

Comment: Is there any chance to improve the performances and possibly do the calculation in parallel for each different string in `inp`?

Comment: A list comprehension is usually no more or less efficient than a regular loop for simple things like this. In this case, it's _less_ efficient because `if s in o` already traverses the list once, and `o.index(s)` does it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary index first to speed-up the search:

```py
inp = ["ans1", "ans2", "ans3"]
output = [
    ["aaa", "ans1", "bbb", "ccc", "ans2", "ddd"],
    ["bbb", "aaa", "ans2", "ddd", "ans1", "aaa"],
    ["ddd", "ccc", "ans2", "ans1", "aaa", "bbb"],
]

tmp = [{v: i for i, v in enumerate(subl)} for subl in output]

result = [[d.get(i, -1) for d in tmp] for i in inp]
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 4, 3], [4, 2, 2], [-1, -1, -1]]
```