# How do I parallelize a for loop that calls a function?

Tags: python

I have the following snippet which iterates over a list of `.csv` files and then uses a `insert_csv_data` function which reads, preprocesses and inserts the `.csv` file's data into a `.hyper` file (*Hyper is Tableau's new in-memory data engine technology, designed for fast data ingest and analytical query processing on large or complex data sets*):

A detailed interpretation of the `insert_csv_data` function can be found [here](https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/main/Tableau-Supported/Python/create_hyper_file_from_csv.py)

```py
for csv in csv_list:
            insert_csv_data(hyper)
```

The issue with the above code is that it inserts one `.csv` file into the `.hyper` file at a time,  which is pretty slow at the moment.

I would like to know if there's a faster or parallel workaround as I'm using Apache Spark for processing on Databricks. I've done some research and found modules like `multiprocessing`,
`joblib` and `asyncio` that might work for my scenario, but I'm unsure of how to correctly implement them.

*Please Advise*

**Edit:**

*Parallel Code:*

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
element_run = Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(insert_csv_data)(csv) for csv in csv_list)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop

Comment: I've tried that, my parallel code takes longer than my original code

Comment: Did you make sure you are cpu bound and not IO bound?

Comment: Not sure, I'll look into it

Comment: I would argue (others may disagree) that the general rule for deciding on one of multithreading or multiprocessing is that if your parallel operations are I/O bound use the former otherwise (CPU bound) use the latter. It would be interesting to see your "parallel code"

Comment: @BrutusForcus I have updated my question, Pardon the inexperience, but how do I know if my operations are I/O or CPU Bound?

Comment: I set `n_jobs =1` and the error disappeared, I presume this will slow down my process?

Comment: @Luke without being able to see your *insert_csv_data* function it's impossible to say whether you're likely to be I/O or CPU bound.

Comment: The `insert_csv_data` function executes a SQL command that copies from the `.csv` to `.hyper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not directly answer the question but demonstrates how multiprocessing and multithreading are easily interchangeable using the concurrent.futures module. Note that the two loops achieve exactly the same thing and that the only difference between the two sections of code the is the work manager class.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor


def tfunc(n):
    return n * n


N = 1_000


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for future in [executor.submit(tfunc, n) for n in range(N)]:
            future.result()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for future in [executor.submit(tfunc, n) for n in range(N)]:
            future.result()


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Comment: No because the two lines of code you're presented make no sense. What is *hyper*? You don't seem to be using *csv*. What does *insert_csv_data* do? Crucial questions that need to be answered

Comment: In that case I suggest you try both techniques and measure the outcome.

Comment: Thank you. Here's a more appropriate [reference](https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/main/Tableau-Supported/Python/create_hyper_file_from_csv.py) if you have the time.

Comment: Given that Hyper seems to be an in-memory technology, I would start with multiprocessing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238012/discussion-between-brutusforcus-and-luke).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html and also just go ahead and adapt my code for your purposes

Comment: `ProcessPoolExecutor` took longer than the usual time, and `ThreadPoolExecutor` didn't work as `Hyper` doesn't support making multiple connections at the same time. Thanks a lot for the assistance, I'll take up the issue with Tableau