# Multi-level multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, multi-level

I am having a little bit of trouble with multiprocessing in python.

I can easily run a **one level multiprocessing**. However, I am stuck when comes to upgrading it to a **two level multiprocessing**. Let me explain, what I am doing now:

I have NBC number of conductors, I want to compute the defining electrical parameters (R,L and C), so I run python script in a one level multiprocessing where R, L and C for each conductor are computed as follow:

```
for i in range(0,NBC):
    compute_R_of_conductor() 
    compute_L_of_conductor()
    compute_C_of_conductor()
```

where, well you guessed it, `compute_R_of_conductor()`, `compute_L_of_conductor()` and `compute_C_of_conductor()` are predefined functions that are run perfectly simultaneously.

I would like to include the part `for i in range(0,NBC)` in the second level of multiprocessing so that I have the electrical parameters of multiple conductors computed at once to speed up even more my computations.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop)

Comment: @JonSG No it does not. I can parallelize one loop, the problem is how to parallelize a nested loop `for i in range(0,NBC): for j in range(0,3)`: