# Looking for a nicer python convention for this code block

Tags: python, pandas

When I'm building out dataframes inside a loop, I often find myself using this convention:

```
complete_df = None
for data_chunk in data_chunks:
    partial_df = get_partial_df(data_chunk)    
    partial_df = do_some_stuff_to_my_df(partial_df)
    if complete_df is None:
        complete_df = partial_df
    else:
        complete_df = complete_df.append(partial_df)
```

I'm looking for a better / shorter / more pythonic way to do this. A ternary statement seems like it wouldn't be an improvement.

Comment: Knowing what `get_partial_df` is (or at least what it returns) would be helpful.

Comment: get_partial_df is going to return a pandas dataframe. This is just pseudocoded.

Comment: Try `df = pd.concat(map(get_partial_df, data_chunks))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do away with the if else block if you initialize the `complete_df` to an empty `DataFrame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

complete_df = pd.DataFrame()
for data_chunk in data_chunks:
    partial_df = get_partial_df(data_chunk)    
    partial_df = do_some_stuff_to_my_df(partial_df)
    complete_df = complete_df.append(partial_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
complete_df = None
for data_chunk in data_chunks:
    partial_df = get_partial_df(data_chunk)    
    complete_df = partial_df if complete_df is None else complete_df.append(partial_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_chunks = range(1, 100, 4)

def get_partial_df(num):
    return num

#complete_df = None
complete_df = list()
print(type(complete_df))
for data_chunk in data_chunks:
    partial_df = get_partial_df(data_chunk)
    complete_df.append(partial_df)

    # if complete_df is None:
    #     complete_df = partial_df  ##here complete_df is int
    # else:
    #    complete_df = complete_df.append(partial_df) ## appending to be done on list/tuple.
```

Comment: defined get_partial_df and data_chunks.. just to make points clear

Comment: Empty lists should be defined by `[]`, not really `list()`.

Comment: @cs95: this is opinion-based suggestion, `list()` is a valid syntax for creating empty lists

Comment: @AzatIbrakov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list

Comment: @U9-Forward: if something is "faster" it doesn't mean that it's better, `list()` is explicit and readable enough, also creating single empty `list` should never be a bottleneck

Comment: @AzatIbrakov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790860/and-vs-list-and-dict-which-is-better/39078199#39078199

Comment: @AzatIbrakov And in general, `[]` is used 99% of the time, and `list()` is only used 1% the time, basically you really almost never see `list()`