# Why use the list() constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just wanted to know the use of the list() constructor because if we want to create a new list then just we can use square brackets, what's the specific use of the list() constructor.

```
newGrocerylist = list(("apple", "guava", "mango", "pineapple", "orange")) #Why use the list() constructor.
print(newGrocerylist)

#We can also do like this--

newGrocerylist = ["apple", "guava", "mango", "pineapple", "orange"]
print(newGrocerylist)
```

Why use the list constructor? Isn't it a redundant thing to do--

```
newGrocerylist = list(("apple", "guava", "mango", "pineapple", "orange"))
```

Comment: While this is pretty basic I think it isn't a duplicate of either of the above. I shd check if "What is X used for" a valid question.

Comment: Indeed, the question itself makes clear that OP does know what the list constructor does. They want to know when to use it to do that. This is a different question. Potentially opinionated, but I don't even think so, since there is general agreement on when to use list(). Definitely isn't duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to create a literal new list with a bunch of new values then you're right. There is no reason to use the list constructor, you should use the literal notation:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In fact, it is impossible to create a new list with a bunch of values using the constructor, you can only use it to transform iterables into their list representation:

```
my_tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c')  # literal notation to create a new tuple
my_list = list(my_tuple)    # this is what you actually did in your first example
```

You can use the other iterable constructors like `set` and `dict` in a similar way. They are not used to create new objects, but transform existing ones into the type they describe.

Comment: `[*my_tuple]`  ;)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps we want to convert a `Map` or `Set` into a `list`. We would pass it into the constructor.

```
mylist = list(myset)
```

Comment: yeah, for casting that, I was new and was studying then, now I know it well, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

`list` can be passed around as a function object.

So as a toy example you could have a function that creates an arbitrary collection and you could pass in either `list` or `set`

```
def make_collection_from_data(data, collection_maker):
    return collection_maker(data)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

make_collection_from_data(data, set) # Returns a list
make_collection_from_data(data, list) # Returns a set
```

Answer (score 0):

In the initial statement you created a tuple (indicated by round brackets) and converted it with `list()`. In the second example you directly created a list (with the square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

They don't behave the same in all contexts. For example, you can construct a list of dictionary keys, or create a list with one element (one dict).

```
>>> list({1:2})
[1]
>>> [{1:2}]
[{1: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, list () constructor uses less memory (thus less execution time) than list(). Check the code below and inform me if I am missing something:)

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(list1)
stop =timer()
print(stop-start)

start =timer()
thislist = list(("apple", "banana", "cherry"))
print (thislist)
stop =timer()
print(stop-start)
```

The results in seconds:
List [0.0003924000193364918] and
list () constructor[0.00016659998800605536]

Comment: I'm sorry but what  is your answer for the qiestion?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Primarily we use a Constructorlist() when there is a string.

```
vowel_string = 'aeiou'
print(list(vowel_string))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['a','e','i','o','u']
```

Answer (score -3):

Check out: [[] and {} vs list() and dict(), which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790860/and-vs-list-and-dict-which-is-better)

It looks like the constructor [] or {} for dicts is much faster than list() or dict().

Comment: This should either be fleshed out, or replaced with a close-as-duplicate vote.