# Is there a way to do a while loop on a variable that's undefined? (How can I rewrite this, Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, walrus-operator

I want to do a while loop that runs until a user puts nothing in the input.

This is what I have that currently works, but I want to remove the `answer = None` instantiation.

```
def answer_as_ul(question, input_prefix='• '):
    print(question)
    answer_list = list()
    answer = None
    while answer != '':
        answer = input(input_prefix)
        answer_list.append(answer) if answer else None
    return answer_list
```

Is there a way to remove `answer = None` here and keep the functionality?

Comment: Using a conditional expression like that is pretty unidiomatic. Which version of Python, can you use `while answer := input(input_prefix):` (available from 3.8, see [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/))?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep! I'm on Pyhton 3.8+. That worked like a charm! Beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to [@jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s beautiful solution using [Python 3.8's walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
def answer_as_ul(question, input_prefix='• '):
    print(question)
    answer_list = list()
    while answer := input(input_prefix):
        answer_list.append(answer)
    return answer_list
```

Comment: This is very Pythonic!

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below. I also added a few minor tweaks for more Pythonic code:

```
def answer_as_ul(question, input_prefix='• '):
    print(question)
    answer_list = []
    while True:
        answer = input(input_prefix)
        if not answer: break
        answer_list.append(answer)
    return answer_list
```

Comment: Is it more pythonic to use `[]` instead of `list()`?

Comment: @ZackPlauché Yes, I think so. I have seen it more often in otherwise good quality code. Maybe because it is shorter...

Comment: You were right! [and they're faster.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790860/and-vs-list-and-dict-which-is-better)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this but it doesn't make a lot of difference :

```
def answer_as_ul(question, input_prefix='• '):
    print(question)
    answer_list = list()
    while True:
        answer = input(input_prefix)
        if answer: break  
        else: answer_list.append(answer)
    return answer_list
```

Comment: Other way around, surely - append the `answer` if it's truthy, break otherwise.