# Different ways to create an empty list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to create an empty list and append some values inside this list. So far I know that if I want to create and empty list I can do it either like this:

```
list1 = []
```

or like this:

```
list1 = list()
```

(My apologies if there is another way that currently I don't know)

My question at this point is if there is a difference between those two ways to create a list; in terms of efficiency for example.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Think it makes any difference, I can not see why you need to declare a new list using the constructor.

`list1 = []` and `list1 = list()` are the same as I know.

If you have literal values you should use the literal notation `list1= ['a', 'b', 'c']`
I don't even think it's possible to create a list with some values using the constructor.

The constructor main usage is when we want to convert a `Map`, `Set` or 'tuple' into a `list`

For example:

```
my_tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c')
my_list = list(my_tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

The literal syntax, `list1 = []`, is slightly faster. There's been a handful of threads on this worth reading:

[[] and {} vs list() and dict(), which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790860/and-vs-list-and-dict-which-is-better)

[Why is [] faster than list()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list)